# Adding surveyed points to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, point, land-survey

I am using arcmap 10.2.

How do i insert survey points that were collected in PNEZD format?

Comment: PNEZD format has not been mentioned on this site before. What is it?

Comment: Sorry, it is a comma delimited point file. PNEZD stands for (point, northing, easting, elevation, description)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is in a CSV, then you can load it into arcmap and right click > Display X Y data.

From there, you can use the Description for symbology.